# How to get "Gallery Photos Paths" in Microsoft MAUI.Net?

Tags: android, ios, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm building a Custom Control (a Gallery Picture Picker)

basically trying to re-make a this : **Microsoft.Maui.Media.MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync()**

but i didn't find anyway to retrieve user pictures on MAUI ..

on **Xamarin.Android** i used this code :

```
var uriExternal = MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri;

string[] projection = { (MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id),
                        (MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.DateAdded), 
                        (MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.RelativePath) };

var cursor = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(uriExternal, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.DateAdded);

if (cursor != null) {
    int columnIndexID = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id);
    int RelativePathID = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.RelativePath);

    while (cursor.MoveToNext()) {
        long imageId = cursor.GetLong(columnIndexID);
        string rPath = cursor.GetString(RelativePathID);

        //Get the Picture's URI
        Android.Net.Uri uriImage = Android.Net.Uri.WithAppendedPath(uriExternal, "" + imageId);
        
        ...
    }
}
```

with this Code, given the required permissions, i could get the external path of all pictures of an Android phone to then use them in my PicturePicking custom control ..

==> how can i do this in Microsoft MAUI !! (targeting Android & IOS)

(just to be clear, of course i know that i could just use **MediaPicker's [PickPhotoAsync]** function, but i clearly don't want that, it's not an option)

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: You can’t directly access the device gallery via a path.  You need to use the relevant API to do it.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! , can you point me towards the relevant API please ?

Comment: you don't mean using the MediaPicker API right ? cause that's not an option (as i've stated on the post)

Comment: Any news on this item? I need to know how to obtain the folder path too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 2 days of searching.. i've came to the conclusion that the only way to do this is by using Plateform Specific Code ..

(i tryed it successfully)

Comment: Can you outline the platform specific code?

Comment: i actually helped some guy with this on here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74446430/how-to-fetch-images-from-gallery-in-collectionview-ios-16-and-android-33-in-net/74448070#74448070